# Regex match substring, but not when prefixed by word

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I have the following two lines, which represent a sample of the type of data I dealing with, which I am currently testing out in regex101.com and also in the Google Chrome console. When finished I wish to use the regex in a Javascript application. The logic is essentially "match the regex, except if it is prefixed by 'Note', where the base regex is /([0-9].[0-9]+[A-Z]?)/"

```
General Note 5.32 5.34 5.36
abcdef 5.33
```

It should match 5.34, 5.36 and 5.33.

This regex works (using a negative lookbehind), but is not useable in Javascript:

```
/(?<!Note )\b([0-9]\.[0-9]+[A-Z]?)/g
```

Based on other Stack Overflow answers, I have attempted to convert it to something that should work in Javascript, but the closest I have is:

```
/^(?!Note).+\b([0-9]\.[0-9]+[A-Z]?)/g
```

On the web site, I am shown this matches the 5.34, but not the 5.33 or 5.36.

Trying it in Chrome console:

```
text = 'General Note 5.32 5.34 5.36\nabcdef 5.33';
text.match(/^(?!Note).+\b([0-9]\.[0-9]+[A-Z]?)/g)
```

Then I get the following, which is also not what I want:

```
["General Note 5.32 5.34 5.36"]
```

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing?

Comment: Should be noted that it's trivial without a regex -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8tauxsg9/

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of lookbehind you can use this alternation based regex and use **captured group #1** for your matches:

```
/\bNote \b\d\.\d+[A-Z]?\b|\b(\d\.\d+[A-Z]?)\b/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK5oT0/1)

**Code:**

```
var re = /\bNote \b\d\.\d+[A-Z]?\b|\b(\d\.\d+[A-Z]?)\b/g; 
var str = 'General Note 5.32 5.34 5.36\nabcdef 5.33';
var m;
var matches = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    if (m[1])
       matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["5.34", "5.36", "5.33"]
```